# Maven spring project opening on notepad

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

In eclipse my maven spring project when clicking on run on server it is opening notepad. The server is working fine when I open http://localhost:8080/Amazon/home.jsp it is working.[the notepad is showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyTLV.png).

I want my project to directly run on web-browser.

Comment: It sounds like your Eclipse IDE is not correctly configured to open web pages in a web browser when you run your Maven Spring project. Try this.
- Go to Window > Preferences (or Eclipse > Preferences on macOS).
- Navigate to General > Web Browser.
- Make sure that Use external web browser is selected. If it's not, select it and choose your preferred web browser from the list. If your preferred browser is not listed, you can add it by clicking on the New button.
- Apply the changes and close the Preferences dialog.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Feel free to mark the answer as correct if you think it solved your problem. @ZONIC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your Eclipse IDE is not correctly configured to open web pages in a web browser when you run your Maven Spring project.

Try this:

- Go to Window > Preferences (or Eclipse > Preferences on macOS).
- Navigate to General > Web Browser.
- Make sure that Use external web browser is selected. If it's not, select it and choose your preferred web browser from the list. If your preferred browser is not listed, you can add it by clicking on the New button.
- Apply the changes and close the Preferences dialog.